# C++ - Value not returning to main.cpp

Tags: c++

I'm currently doing an assignment for c++ where I grab values from a .txt file and average those numbers then write that average to a new .txt file 
I did all that and called on the functions in the main.cpp but the average value isn't being returned and I don't know how to resolve this issue.  Can someone help me?

Here's the code: 
computeaverage.cpp

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include "computeaverage.hpp"
using namespace std;

double compute_average(double average) {
  double total = 0, count = 0;
  int value;
  ifstream inFile;

  inFile.open("data.txt");

  while (inFile >> value) {
    count++;
    total += value;
  }

  inFile.close();
  average = total/count;
  return average;
}

double write_avg_to_file(double average) {
  ofstream outFile;

  outFile.open("solution.txt");
  outFile << average;
  outFile.close();
}
```

computeraverage.hpp

```
double compute_average(double average);
double write_avg_to_file(double average);
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "computeaverage.hpp"
using namespace std;

int main() {
  double average = 0;
  compute_average(average);

  cout << "The average is " << average << endl;

  write_avg_to_file(average);

  return 0;
}
```

Thank you for the help

Comment: you didnt assign return value to average variable line `average=compute_average(average);`

Comment: Read [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: If input file cannot be opened or is empty you have undefined behaviour (divide by zero).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the `average` by reference, its value will exists after returning from `compute_average` function:

In computeraverage.hpp replace

```
double compute_average(double average);
```

with

```
void compute_average(double& average);
```

In computeaverage.cpp replace

```
double compute_average(double average) {
```

with

```
void compute_average(double& average) {
```

and delete

```
return average;
```

Comment: I would prefer return value. Using return value enables functional programming (directly use result of function as argument for another function). Also you can assign the result to a constant, which isn't possible with pass-by-reference. Last not least it makes the code easier to read, as you don't have to look up the function signature to see that the argument will be modified.

Answer (score 2):

`compute_average` takes `average` by value, and `average` is never assigned to (apart from the 0 initialization) in the main function. Use it like this:

```
double average = compute_average();
```

And remove the parameter of `compute_average`, which isn't used anyway.

Comment: Or pass it by reference instead of value and don’t return a double.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the world of C++ programming. I see you have accepted Emil's answer but as zett42 suggested there may be better ways.

Returning results from a function in its arguments is a powerful technique, one which you will have to use if you maintain or interface with C code, legacy C++ or a different language through a C API. The technique does have pitfalls which should be avoided whenever possible. The best way to do this is to use the power of your tools. If you are using a recent compiler and you add options to issue all warnings, and consider warnings as errors; for g++ "-Wall -Werror" the compiler will provide some assitance. There will be times - like those discussed above - where you will need to disable these, but certainly while you are learning or working you will find the reporting helpful. If you build your code with these options on you will get the following messages:

```
computeaverage.cpp: In function double write_avg_to_file(double):
computeaverage.cpp:33:1: error: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Werror=return-type]
```

Changing the declaration of `write_avg_to_file` to `void write_avg_to_file(double);` silences those messages.

In addition, if you are using C++17, you can declare functions that return values with a nodiscard attribute (if you aren't using C++17 there are other, less portable ways, to specify this):

```
[[nodiscard]] double compute_average(double average);
```

Which will provide the following diagnostics:

```
main.cpp: In function int main():
main.cpp:7:20: error: ignoring return value of double compute_average(double), declared with attribute nodiscard [-Werror=unused-result]
 compute_average(average);
```

Changing the offending line to `average = compute_average(average);` silences those messages and the program runs as expected. However passing `average` into `compute_average` is unnecessary so the files can be re-written as:

**computeaverage.hpp**

```
[[nodiscard]] double compute_average();
void write_avg_to_file(double average);
```

**computeaverage.cpp**

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include "computeaverage.hpp"
using namespace std;

double compute_average() {
    double total = 0, count = 0;
    int value;
    ifstream inFile;

    inFile.open("data.txt");

    while (inFile >> value) {
        count++;
        total += value;
    }

    inFile.close();
    double average = total/count;
    return average;
}

void write_avg_to_file(double average) {
    ofstream outFile;

    outFile.open("solution.txt");
    outFile << average;
    outFile.close();
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "computeaverage.hpp"
using namespace std;

int main() {
    double average = 0;
    average = compute_average();

    cout << "The average is " << average << endl;

    write_avg_to_file(average);

    return 0;
}
```

Of course there are still error checks that you could be making, but hopefully these suggestions help you, or others, in future projects.